# how to get data for Two json urls in iOS

Tags: ios, json, uitextfield, uipickerview

I know only getting data for Json.But i need how to getting data for two json url.
i have two Urls and two MutableArrays.Ever time i can handle only one url like this :-

```
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:@" url"];
NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
if(connection)
{
   NSLog(@"Connected");
   webData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
   NSLog(@"Connected2");
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    return arrayfirst.count;

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return arrayfirst[row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    one.text = arrayfirst[row];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

            NSMutableArray *al=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];

            NSLog(@"the array is %@",al);

            for(NSArray *arr in al)
            {
                [arrayfirst addObject:[arr objectAtIndex:1]];
            }
  }
```

Please give me any idea about how to handle two Json url. I have two urls `BusinessCategory` and `BusinessLocation` I have two `MutableArrays` `arrayfirst` and `arraysecond`. I know about `BusinessCategory` data pass to `arrayfirst`. But I don't know how to handle.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to ask? Be more specific.

Comment: @Xeieshan i have two UITextFields and i have  UIpickerview and two json urls.json data pass to uipickerview based on textFileds So Please give me any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create two NSURL connection and handle the response in the delegate.

```
So, in your header file you can have:

NSURLConnection *conn1;
NSURLConnection *conn2;
NSMutableArray *arrayFirst;
NSMutableArray *arraySecond;

In the implementation file:

//Connection 1
NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourjsonurl1"];
NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];
conn1=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request1 delegate:self];

//Connection 2
NSURL *url2=[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourjsonurl2"];
NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
conn2=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request2 delegate:self];

//In your delegate
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    if (connection==conn1) {
        arrayFirst = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
    else if (connection==conn2){
        arraySecond = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    if (connection==conn1) {
        [arrayFirst appendData:data];
    }
    else if (connection==conn2){
        [arraySecond appendData:data];
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (connection==conn1) {
       NSLog(@"SOMETHING WENT WRONG WITH URL1");
    }
    else if (connection==conn2){
        NSLog(@"SOMETHING WENT WRONG WITH URL2");
    }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    if (connection==conn1) {
       NSLog(@"DONE WITH URL1");
    }
    else if (connection==conn2){
        NSLog(@"DONE WITH URL2");
    }
}
```

A shorter (and maybe, better) way of doing this is to run it in an asynchronous operation:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData *result = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:"yourURL"];
    id jsonResult;
    if ([result length] != 0) { jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:0 error:nil];}
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"done!");
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried as you said but in connectionDidFinishLoading I tried like this  if (connection==con1) {
      
 NSLog(@"DONE WITH URL1");
     NSMutableArray *al=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
      NSLog(@"first array is %@",al);
  }
 else if (connection==con2){
  NSLog(@"DONE WITH URL2");
       NSMutableArray *al2=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData2 options:0 error:nil];
     
     NSLog(@"second array is %@",al2);
    
 } but it's only display second array first array data is not display So Please give any idea